# Using YouTube API, is it possible to filter search by upload date?

Tags: youtube-api

I'm working on a personal project to retrieve YouTube videos on a particular subject very quickly after they are posted. Using the "Sort By" filter works well, however, I've noticed that some videos that fit the search query do not appear in the HTML. So, I was wondering if it is possible to also sort by Upload date, similar to the YouTube feature which allows for filtering videos based on if they were posted in the last hour, today, this week, etc. I believe that if I could include a filter for videos posted in the last hour, that would improve the accuracy of my project.
Any help is very much appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! Please take the time to absorb [SO's recommendations](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) addressed to new users. You may take the [tour]; then do read [what's on-topic here](/help/on-topic) and provide a [mre].

Answer (score 0):

Check out the "order" parameter in this [API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list?apix_params=%7B%22part%22%3A%5B%22snippet%22%5D%2C%22order%22%3A%22date%22%2C%22publishedAfter%22%3A%222020-12-26T00%3A00%3A00Z%22%7D) (can set it to "date").